# Adding static files to Talend jobs

Tags: csv, talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Big Data and I have a job where I use tFileInputDelimited to load a CSV file and use it as a lookup with a tMap.

Currently the file is loaded from the disk using an absolute path (`C:\work\jobs\lookup.csv`) and everything works fine locally.

The issue is that when I deploy the task, it obviously doesn't take the lookup.csv file with it.

Which begs a question:

Is there any way to "bundle" this file (lookup.csv) into the job so I can later deploy them together?

Comment: sorry but not very clear on what you want..do you want to read more than one csv files - where you give the path of file dynamically or you want to know how to deploy this job?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.. What I want is to have some job assets (i.e. external files) contained somehow withing a job and later referenced inside it, For example: Instead of loading an external file by giving an absolute path, I'd be giving a path like '/resources/myLookup.csv' where 'resources' is inside the job itself.

Comment: After exporting job you can import it in eclipse to create ANT build, inside Build.xml you can specify what are the files need to be bundled and their output location. this way you can bundled external things with talend job. but as of now Talend is not supporting this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With static data such as this your best bet is to hard code the data into the job using a tFixedFlowInput instead.

As an example, if we want to use a list of country names, their ISO2 and ISO3 codes you might have these in a CSV that you'd normally access with a tFileInputDelimited. However, to save bundling this CSV with every build (which could be done with ANT/Maven) you can just hard code this data into a tFixedFlowInput:

[image: tFixedFlowInput component with hard coded comma delimited country data]

You then just need to make sure your schema is set up as the same as your delimited file would have been (so in this case we have 3 columns: `Country_Name`, `ISO2` and `ISO3`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm already familiar with this approach, and I'm using it with a simpler look-up already. Unfortunately I want to be bale to change the values without re-deploying the job so I ended up creating a database-based look-up table. Thank you anyway, I think this will be very helpful to others. Marked.